# Glide library taking too long to display blur images

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, blur

I'm using Glide library to display images with blur transform, but its taking too long to display. It takes around 6-8 seconds to display the blur image. 
Images I want to display are locally saved.

Images without blur loads almost instantly.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
    .load(img)
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .transform(new BlurTransformation(), new CenterCrop())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.back)
    .error(R.drawable.back)
    .into(layout);
```

I also tried passing parameters to `BlurTransformation()` like the following, but none works.

```
new BlurTransformation(context)
new BlurTransformation(25)
new BlurTransformation(25, 5)
```

This is what I have in my `build.gradle` related to Glide:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'
```

I used Picasso library earlier and it was working fine with the blur transform, but Glide is taking too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GLIDE**
Hey,
IF you see the documentation of glide blur transformation code,

```java
@Override   
protected Bitmap transform(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull BitmapPool pool,@NonNull Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {

    int width = toTransform.getWidth();
    int height = toTransform.getHeight();
    int scaledWidth = width / sampling;
    int scaledHeight = height / sampling;

    Bitmap bitmap = pool.get(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.scale(1 / (float) sampling, 1 / (float) sampling);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFlags(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    canvas.drawBitmap(toTransform, 0, 0, paint);

    bitmap = FastBlur.blur(bitmap, radius, true);

    return bitmap;   
}
```

Its performing operation on bitmap, If your image size is bigger then it will take time to perform operation on bitmap, -Please user lighter image -You can perform the blur operation by self. -You need to display loader until your operation is not performed over bitmap.

========================================================================

Comment: Thanks, I never had a look at the definition of that function.